# Why does my break call the previous function

Tags: python-2.7, function, break

I have two functions and the first one calls the second one.  However, when I break out of the second function it displays text from an if statement in the first function.  What I don't understand, is why is the second function calling the first? Secondly, I do not understand why it would execute code from an if statement where the condition has never been met.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

'''A sorting app where the user gets to choose 

between options and the options are ranked by 

likes in a file stored on a file'''

import sys
import random
import pickle 

def intro():
    greeting = '''\nWelcome to chooser where your voice gets to be heard

Press Enter to begin greatness
Press anything else to be immediately banned
>>'''
    enter = raw_input(greeting).lower()
    if enter == '':
        main()
    if enter == 'admin':
        print 'Entering Admin menu\n'
        admin()
    else:
        print '''\nDid you think I was kidding?!
You're gone!\n'''
        sys.exit()
# Enters the main program if the user presses Enter or else it quits 
def main():
    count = 0
    while True:
        nav = '''Type Go to play
Type Q to quit
Type admin to go to admin
>>'''
        start = raw_input(nav).lower()
        if start == 'q':
            print '\nThank you for playing\nBye!\n'
            break
        else:
            print 'Any other key restarts the function'
def chooser():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    intro()

'''                         -----Questions-----
Why does this function when it expires run the intro function instead of just 
running out of scope????'''
```

This is what prints out of the terminal:

[image: terminal output]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what happens? Perhaps copy-paste a terminal session where you ran this script and saw unexpected behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 I posted a picture of what the terminal output looked like, unfortunately I'm not at my computer but I'll edit the question with a proper screenshot in a little bit

Comment: cannot reproduce here. Seems to work normally. Tested with python 2 and python 3 (with input instead of raw_input and fixed prints); Press Enter to start
Press anything else to be immediately banned
>>
Type Q to quit
>>q

Thank you for playing
Bye!

Comment: Worked well here too. python 2.7 and 3.3 on RHEL. Try removing the compiled code .pyc file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you for your help, I updated the code and looked for why this was happening and found the issue to be something associated with the line "if enter == 'admin'"  once again any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @alvits I updated the code to highlight where I was getting the problem

Comment: The output is correct. When `main()` returned to the caller which is `intro()`, it proceeded to the next statement `if enter=='admin':` but the value of enter wasn't `admin` so it went to `else` and printed `Did you think I was kidding?!`. So what was the problem? The break never called any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically at the part:

```
if enter == '':
    main()
if enter == 'admin':
    print 'Entering Admin menu\n'
    admin()
else:
    print '''\nDid you think I was kidding?!
```

you have two seperete statements, one 'if' and one 'if-else' following it.
the first checks if the input is '', this condition holds in your example, so main() is called and everythig is fine.
when main() returns, you exit the first statement and enter the second, which checks if the input is admin (this is false), and if not it does the printing.

the logic here is:

- if enter is '', run main().
- if enter is 'admin', run admin().
- if enter is not 'admin', print the message.

the else part is not related at all to the first if (only to the second). what you need to do is to replace the second 'if' with an 'elif', thus making a single 'if-elif-else' statement, so the logic will be:

- if enter is '', run main().
- if enter is not '', and enter is 'admin', run admin().
- if enter is not '', and not 'admin', print the message.